# In SSRS, How to display past sales summarized results based on date parameter?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012

I'm building an SSRS report that shows basic sales history for items sold. The user inputs the item #, start date and end date as parameters. The main table displays sales information row-by-row for the item entered and for sales dates between start/end dates.

As part of the report, I would like to include some key summarized data in text boxes that would show:

- Qty. Sold Last 6 Months
- Qty. Sold This Year
- Qty. Sold Last Year

It would be even better if I could label those as "Qty. Sold in 2022" (for last year), and have that update based on the Start Date parameter entered. So if the user entered a Start Date of sometime in 2021, it would then show as "Qty. Sold in 2020".

I'm struggling to know how to summarize the quantity and change the date range being looked at based on the Start Date and End Date.

**Sample Data:**

**Parameters:** Start Date=Jan/01/2023 End Date=Feb/28/2023 Item No.=009833

| Posting Date | Order No. | Customer | Item No. | Qty. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan/01/2023 | 25467 | Joe Smith | 009833 | 4 |
| Feb/06/2023 | 26802 | Peter | 009833 | 27 |
| Feb/20/2023 | 26980 | Sandra W. | 009833 | 11 |

****Edited to add code 8/18/2023:****

```
WITH        
    
----This CTE Gathers Sales Invoice / Cr. Memo Header data from 4 different sources----

    CTE_SalesHeaderData (DocN, NoSeries, OrderNo, PostingDate, Cust_Name)       
    AS      
(SELECT SIH.[No_], SIH.[No_ Series], SIH.[Order No_], SIH.[Posting Date], SIH.[Sell-to Customer Name]       
FROM [Sales Invoice Header] SIH         

UNION ALL           
SELECT SCRMH.[No_], SCRMH.[No_ Series], SCRMH.[Order No_], SCRMH.[Posting Date], SCRMH.[Sell-to Customer Name]          
FROM [Sales Cr_Memo Header] SCRMH   
        
UNION ALL           
SELECT SVIH.[No_], SVIH.[No_ Series], SVIH.[Order No_], SVIH.[Posting Date], SVIH.[Bill-to Name]    
FROM [Service Invoice Header] SVIH  

UNION ALL           
SELECT SVCRMH.[No_], SVCRMH.[No_ Series], SVCRMH.[Order No_], SVCRMH.[Posting Date], SVCRMH.[Bill-to Name]          
FROM [Service Cr_Memo Header] SVCRMH),

----This CTE Gathers Sales Invoice / Cr. Memo Line data for the 4 sources (relates to the 4 sources in 1st CTE) ----

CTE_SalesLinesData (DocNo2,ItemNo,Qty)  
AS
(SELECT SIL.[Document No_], SIL.[No_], SIL.[Quantity]
FROM [Sales Invoice Line] SIL
WHERE SIL.[Type] <> '1'
GROUP BY SIL.[Document No_], SIL.[No_], SIL.[Quantity]

UNION ALL
SELECT SCRML.[Document No_], SCRML.[No_], SCRML.[Quantity]
FROM [Sales Cr_Memo Line] SCRML
WHERE SCRML.[Type] <> '1'
GROUP BY SCRML.[Document No_], SCRML.[No_], SCRML.[Quantity]

UNION ALL
SELECT SVIL.[Document No_], SVIL.[No_], SVIL.[Quantity]
FROM [Service Invoice Line] SVIL
WHERE SVIL.[Type] = '1' OR SVIL.[Type] = '2'
GROUP BY SVIL.[Document No_], SVIL.[No_], SVIL.[Quantity]

UNION ALL
SELECT SVCRML.[Document No_], SVCRML.[No_], SVCRML.[Quantity]
FROM [Service Cr_Memo Line] SVCRML
WHERE SVCRML.[Type] = '1' OR SVCRML.[Type] = '2'
GROUP BY SVCRML.[Document No_], SVCRML.[No_], SVCRML.[Quantity])

SELECT
SHD.[PostingDate],
SHD.[OrderNo],
SHD.[Cust_No],
SHD.[Cust_Name],
SLD.[ItemNo],

---- The qty. has to be manipulated as it needs to be negative if it was a Cr. Memo ----
CASE
WHEN SHD.[NoSeries] = 'SI' THEN SLD.[Qty]
WHEN SHD.[NoSeries] = 'PSI' THEN SLD.[Qty]
WHEN SHD.[NoSeries] = 'SC' THEN SLD.[Qty] * (-1)
WHEN SHD.[NoSeries] = 'PSC' THEN SLD.[Qty] * (-1)
END AS [Qty.]

---- The 1st CTE is joined to the 2nd CTE ----
FROM CTE_SalesHeaderData SHD
LEFT JOIN CTE_SalesLinesData SLD ON SLD.DocNo2 = SHD.[DocN]

GROUP BY
SHD.[PostingDate],
SHD.[DocN],
SHD.[NoSeries],
SHD.[OrderNo],
SHD.[Cust_No],
SHD.[Cust_Name],
SLD.[ItemNo],
SLD.[Qty]

HAVING
SLD.[Qty] > 0
AND (SHD.[PostingDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
AND (SLD.[ItemNo] = @ItemNo)

ORDER BY
SHD.[PostingDate]
```

Please let me know if more information is needed or any other question. Thank you.

Comment: I often use a separate query to get the summary info.

Comment: @DaleK A separate query could make sense for sure. But how to structure it so it will grab past sales data based on the Start/End date parameters?

Comment: Um, exactly the same way as you do to get your current data?

Comment: Sorry I meant separate dataset. I could use a separate dataset for the summary info that just has Posting Date and Quantity to simplify what's involved. But for this to work, both datasets would have to work from the same query and parameters. hopefully there is a way without it being a separate query altogether.

Comment: Well I would do it using a stored procedure that takes in your existing parameters plus an additional parameter `ShowSummary` and then inside you can use an identical query, but if `ShowSummary` is true you group the results before returning them.

Comment: Personally I would create a new dataset that uses a dataset query that only returns those specific values, you can calculate the start and end dates for the summary data based on you parameter values. You could do it all in a single dataset and add columns to the current results to hold the summary info (even though every row will have the same value) but I find it cleaner to just separate them.

Comment: @AlanSchofield The part I need help with is "you can calculate the start and end dates for the summary data based on you parameter values." Can you provide an example? Would you be doing this in SQL or an expression ?

Comment: @adhocEY the same way you do it for your existing query? You are already using your parameter values of start and end  date to generate your full data, just use them exactly the same way to get your summary data? Its not clear to us what you are stuck on given you appear to have already done it once?

Comment: And when I said about using the stored procedure, I meant create another dataset which calls the SP, and have your existing dataset call the SP, so you can ensure the logic is encapsulated in one place.

Comment: @DaleK Yes, I'm using parameter values already but if the user inputs Start Date = Jan/1/2023 End Date = Jul/31/2023 then the full data I need isn't generated because I need data for the previous 6 mths, 1 year etc before those dates...  So that's what I'm stuck on. I don't have any prior experience with stored procedures, so if there's a way to not use them (as another user mentioned) then I would first try that.

Comment: I would highly recommend learning about stored procedures as they will make you life much easier in the long run, and they aren't difficult, they are essentially a way to contain a bunch of sql statements.

Comment: So for your second dataset use `dataadd(month, -6, @StartDate)` in your query, or something similar, to create the needed values?

Comment: Can you see why we are struggling to assist you? Its not clear to us exactly what you are stuck on...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your own DDL/DML (which does really help answering this sort of question), so I used my own randomized data, which is a pretty simple sales type setup.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2023-01-01', @EndDate DATETIME = '2023-02-28 23:59:59.997', @ProductID INT = 5;

;WITH ProductHistory AS (
SELECT ii.ProductID, SUM(CASE WHEN InvoiceDateTimeUTC > DATEADD(MONTH,-6,@StartDate) THEN ii.Quantity END) AS LastSixMonths, 
                     SUM(CASE WHEN InvoiceDateTimeUTC BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,@StartDate)-1,1,1) AND DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,@StartDate),1,1) THEN ii.Quantity END) AS PreviousCalendarYear
  FROM InvoiceItems ii
    INNER JOIN Invoices i
      ON ii.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
 WHERE ii.ProductID = @ProductID
   AND i.InvoiceDateTimeUTC >= DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,@StartDate)-1,1,1)
 GROUP BY ProductID
)

SELECT i.InvoiceDateTimeUTC, i.InvoiceID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, ii.ProductID, SUM(ii.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, ph.LastSixMonths, ph.PreviousCalendarYear, DATEPART(YEAR,@StartDate)-1 AS PreviousYearNumber
  FROM InvoiceItems ii
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductHistory ph
      ON ii.ProductID = ph.ProductID
    INNER JOIN Invoices i
      ON ii.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
    INNER JOIN Customers c
      ON i.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
 WHERE ii.ProductID = @ProductID
   AND InvoiceDateTimeUTC BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 GROUP BY i.InvoiceDateTimeUTC, i.InvoiceID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, ii.ProductID, ph.LastSixMonths, ph.PreviousCalendarYear;
```

We're using a `CTE` here to do the aggregation you want by manipulating the input parameters, and then just joining to that `CTE`. It's non-trivial to bring back dynamic column names, but you can add the PreviousYearNumber column to your header.

| InvoiceDateTimeUTC | InvoiceID | FirstName | LastName | ProductID | TotalQuantity | LastSixMonths | PreviousCalendarYear | PreviousYearNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-11 14:55:15.9633333 | 357 | George | Campbell | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |
| 2023-02-03 15:41:15.9633333 | 951 | Dorothy | Rivera | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |
| 2023-02-24 16:23:15.9633333 | 1722 | Debra | Mendoza | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |
| 2023-01-23 15:19:15.9633333 | 3080 | Ronald | Gomez | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |
| 2023-01-05 14:43:15.9633333 | 4455 | Rachel | Hughes | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |
| 2023-02-27 16:28:15.9633333 | 5898 | Deborah | Roberts | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |
| 2023-02-16 16:06:15.9633333 | 6070 | Ronald | Gomez | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |
| 2023-01-27 15:26:15.9633333 | 7163 | William | Hernandez | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |
| 2023-02-12 15:59:15.9633333 | 7482 | Shirley | Ortiz | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |
| 2023-01-17 15:07:15.9633333 | 7959 | Ryan | Collins | 5 | 1 | 9030 | 8135 | 2022 |

Comment: You're right I should have included DDL/DML. I've updated my post with code. I'm struggling to adapt your method to my code as the amount of CTEs and some of the formatting has me confused. How would you go about applying it to my code?

Comment: Your question still doesn't contain DDL/DML. You can supply some using something like: `DECLARE @TableName (ColumnOne INT, ColumnTwo VARCHAR(20)...); INSERT INTO @TableName (ColumnOne, ColumnTwo...) VALUES (1, 'One'...),(2, 'Two'...) ...;` for as many tables are relevant. I'd suggest at least the invoice header and line items.

Comment: In the example the customer and date information is stored in the `Invoices` table and the line items in the `InvoiceItems` table. Joining those two together we can filter on the date and product (by it's `ProductID`). Using this we can aggregate over the periods you asked for. This can then be joined back to the original tables and displayed per invoice as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very generic sample of how I would approach this.

You currently have a working report as far as I can tell that shows sales data between two dates. I am therefore assuming your dataset query looks something along these lines

```
SELECT * 
    FROM mySalesTable 
    WHERE ItemNo = @ItemNo 
        AND PostingDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Now you want to add some additional summary info, but the data is not captured in your main dataset as that only has data available between two specific points.

So, I would create another dataset called for example `dsSummary` and write a new query for this. Something like..

```
declare @Last6Months INT
declare @LastYear INT 
declare @ThisYear INT 

-- get last 6 monmths from startdate
SELECT @Last6Months = SUM(qty) 
    FROM mySalesTable 
    WHERE ItemNo = @ItemNo 
        AND PostingDate BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -6, @StartDate) AND @StartDate

-- get last year 
SELECT @LastYear = SUM(qty) 
    FROM mySalesTable 
    WHERE ItemNo = @ItemNo 
        AND YEAR(PostingDate) = YEAR(@StartDate)-1

-- get this year 
SELECT @ThisYear = SUM(qty) 
    FROM mySalesTable 
    WHERE ItemNo = @ItemNo 
        AND YEAR(PostingDate) = YEAR(@StartDate)

SELECT 
    @Last6Months as Last6Months,
    @LastYear as LastYear,
    @ThisYear as ThisYear
```

This just uses the `@StartDate` parameter that you already have and runs 3 queries based on that and returns a single row containing the three results.

You could write this differently as it's not very efficient but I've kept it simple so it's easy to follow.

Now you have the new dataset you can add textboxes to your report and set the expressions to `=FIRST(Fields!Last6Month.Value, "dsSummary")` for example.

Comment: I've added my own code (which I should have done previously!) I've played around with trying to adapt your method and get it working but haven't had luck so far. Given the layout/format of my code, how would you approach it?